# Computational complexity of CVaR calculation

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, random-walks, monte-carlo

I am currently looking for literature discussing the computational complexity of [CVaR calculation](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/conditional_value_at_risk.asp). At this point the only work I have found is the following.

[Mavronicolas, Marios, and Burkhard Monien. "Conditional Value-at-Risk: Structure and complexity of equilibria." Theoretical Computer Science 807 (2020): 266-283.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397519305596)

Any other pointer would be greatly appreciated. TIA

Comment: Have you tried doing a literature search, starting from that paper, and seeing what it cites, and looking on Google Scholar to check out the papers that cite it?

Comment: @D.W., it is cited by 3 papers and probably the most relevant one is Georgiou, Chryssis, Marios Mavronicolas, and Burkhard Monien. "The complexity of (E+ Var)-equilibria, ESR-equilibria, and SuperE-equilibria for 2-players games with few cost values." Theoretical Computer Science 860 (2021): 84-97..

Comment: @D.W., I have also found Mhammedi, Zakaria, Benjamin Guedj, and Robert C. Williamson. "Pac-bayesian bound for the conditional value at risk." Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems 33 (2020): 17919-17930.

Comment: Great.  Please incorporate this into your post, by editing your post, rather than by adding comments here.